# I want my background image's opacity become .2 when I hover over an element on top of it

Tags: css

So I have a movie poster image and a play icon on it. How do I make my poster's opacity down WHEN I hover over the play image/icon that is positioned on it?

Comment: @JatinSinghal `'Background-image' != <img>`

Comment: can you share your HTML & CSS code?

Comment: https://github.com/ahmetomerv/MovieOne @jatin-singhal

Comment: You work with jQuery or vanilla only?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myImage').hover(function() {
    // changing the opacity of the poster when hovering over image
    $('#myPoster').css('opacity', '0.2');
  }, function() {
    // resetting opacity when mouse leaves image
    $('#myPoster').css('opacity', '1.0');
  });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that Jquery? not vanilla javascript?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only by css. You need JS events for it.

Check this snippet out

```js
function changeOpacity(){
  document.getElementById('video').style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

```css
#play {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZvwc.png" id="play" onmouseover="changeOpacity();" />
<br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAM35.jpg" id="video" />
```

This way you can change the opacity as per your need.

Enjoy :D

Note: You can use onmouseout event to make the image's (or video's) opacity    back to normal just like that.